# Result code 0 in POST in Swagger UI

Tags: java, web-services, rest, post, swagger

When I use POST from the Swagger UI, the response code is 0. But when I run the generated CURL command in the command line, it works.
In my Swagger UI, GET method works. The problem happens only for POST.

```
@ApiParam(value = "test", required = true, allowMultiple = false) final myclass objectA)
```

Comment: Can you please add more information to your question: Things like What have you tried so far? How does the API look like? What's the CURL command you used? Even maybe an screenshot from the Swagger UI page? Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701976/swagger-ui-for-rails-api-using-activemodels-serializer) as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was as same as [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332882/missing-token-access-control-allow-headers-in-cors-header-access-control-allo). Need to add Access-Control-Allow-Headers